# HTML Form - Sending multiple parameters in action

Tags: html

My deepest apologies if this has been asked before, but I was having trouble wording it and couldn't find anything else.

I have a form with a dropdown selection, and when the user selects an option I want it to add #something so it redirects them to a preset position on my webpage that I set up with .

Trouble is I can't make it work.

```
            <form action="index.html">
              <select name="dropdownMain" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Test">Test</option>
                <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
                <option value="Chicken">Chicken</option>
              </select>
            </form>
```

If I add a # to the value of the options, the url would look like this:

http://localhost/mike/index.html?dropdownMain=%23Test

Is there any way I can do this simply? Or can I add multiple things into the "action" part. For instance:

```
<form action="index.html#" + value>
```

Again, I am sorry if this has already been requested, or if I am missing something ridiculously obvious.

Comment: Create an ID for the element you want to navigate to within the webpage. Then, in your options, add an anchor tag that goes to that element like this `<option><a href = "#insert_id_here_you_need_the_hashtag"></a></option`

Answer (score 0):

I wont recommend to include such parameters in the action property through appending `#`. Here are the 2 options I can suggest

1. Use JS/JQuery libraries to move control another preset position onto the HTML page. You may consider some TAB related libraries for a guideline purpose.
2. Hidden fields in the form - You can always add `HIDDEN` fields to the form and which can further be manipulated in JS / JQUERY to move to preset positions.